# Как уменьшить и сделать отступ thumb в switch?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Надо собрать Switch так как нарисовано в Figma.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получилось только вот что:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch_is_by_near"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/indent_big"
    android:checked="true"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/switch_back"/>
```

switch_thumb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#5DCB68"/>
            <size android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

switch_back:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="#5DCB68" android:width="2dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <padding android:bottom="15dp" android:top="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как хотя бы добавить отступ thumb от бэкграунта?

Comment: Посмотрите [примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726408/switch-button-thumb-gets-skewed). Если добавить, например, `<stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />` в `switch_thumb` отступ появится.

Comment: Да но тогда этот отступ перекроет track я уже пробовал не то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел библиотеку где это реализуется, правда теперь придется код переписывать:
https://github.com/RiccardoMoro/RMSwitch
И еще спасибо  Andrey Mihalev что посоветовал нужную тему, не все понял, но вот что насобирал получилось похоже:
thumb_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
            <size android:width="19dp" android:height="20dp" />
            <stroke android:width="7dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#5DCB68" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
            <size android:width="19dp" android:height="20dp" />
            <stroke android:width="7dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    
</selector>
```

track_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="18dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5DCB68"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#27170432" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="18dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5DCB68"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch_is_by_near"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/indent_big"
  android:checked="true"
  android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_selector"
   android:track="@drawable/track_selector"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]